# Duda con diseño en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo una duda con respecto al diseño de una interfaz en C#.

Quisiera saber si es posible que a través de un *Item* de un *MenuStrip* puedo cambiar el diseño de la interfaz. Es decir, no quiero que se abra una nueva ventana, quiero que se modifique la interfaz según el ítem seleccionado en el *MenuStrip*. Como no sé como definir esto, dejaré unas capturas para que sea más ilustrativo:

Supongamos que tenemos el siguiente menú, me gustaría que al presionar **ImprimirPDF** me salgan esos items:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Y que si presiono **VerPDF**, me muestre esos otros items:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Es posible?

Comment: Claro que es posible, tendrás que jugar con la visibilidad de los controles, según el item del menú seleccionado.

Comment: O sea, que, tengo que superponer los controles?

Comment: Exacto, aunque es mejor ponerlos dentro de un contenedor, del tipo GroupBox u otro para facilitarte la vida.

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Comment: No.. no tenes que jugar con la visibilidad de los controles. Lo mejor es poner todo eso en user controls, y luego mostrar u ocultar el user control que vos queres. De esa forma, centralizas la funcionalidad en un solo lugar y no tenes todo en el mismo formulario....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias poner en el `form` un control `Panel` cagando en este un `User Control` segun que quieres visualizar.

[Windows Forms: How to Create and use User Control in C#](https://foxlearn.com/article/how-to-create-and-use-user-control-in-csharp-276.html)

usando la opcion de menu

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces segun el menu que se pulse podras cargar un control u otro

```
public void menuitem1_Click(...)
{
  Panel1.Controls.Clear();

  var uc1 = new UserControl1();
  Panel1.Controls.Add(uc1);
}

public void menuitem2_Click(...)
{
  Panel1.Controls.Clear();

  var uc2 = new UserControl2();
  Panel1.Controls.Add(uc2);
}
```

asi de simple puedes cambiar la vista

Comment: No existe el control panel en `WindowForm` de` C#`

Comment: Ha sido excelente tu ejemplo, me ha servido bastante. Muchas gracias :)